# Chrome packaged application - downloading file from Webview

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am working on getting an existing Ajax style web application functional as a Chrome packaged app. The Ajax app is running in a Webview inside the packaged app and is mostly working great.

The Ajax app allows users to upload documents using standard HTML 5 upload and drag/drop. Uploads work fine but **downloads are not working**.

This is a simplified sample of the logic in the Ajax app. It uses Javascript to handle the click event, performs some logic, and then eventually triggers the download by setting the location of a hidden IFrame.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadFile(url) {
    window.frames['dataTransfer'].location = url;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br/>
  <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/LYHKDevA1/2058e6cab4304af3a39eeb275eeac96d?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22TestFile.pdf%22%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27TestFile.pdf&Signature=FUlZZqNoJ%2F%2FvHIPX6CPDkvJ7uik%3D&Expires=1437854276&AWSAccessKeyId=1ZAN0NYFJ2DCQX8AN8G2" target="_blank">Download PDF</a><br/>
  <a href="#" onclick="downloadFile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/LYHKDevA1/2058e6cab4304af3a39eeb275eeac96d?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22TestFile.pdf%22%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27TestFile.pdf&Signature=FUlZZqNoJ%2F%2FvHIPX6CPDkvJ7uik%3D&Expires=1437854276&AWSAccessKeyId=1ZAN0NYFJ2DCQX8AN8G2');return false;" target="_blank">Download PDF JS</a><br/>
  <iframe name="dataTransfer" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: none;"></iframe><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this in a standard Chrome tab all 3 links work fine. However in a Chrome App only the first 2 links work - clicking the 3rd link does nothing. In the network section of the Developer tools it actually appears to start the download but then is quickly cancelled.

The manifest of the Chrome app allows Webview and the relevant domains involved.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Download",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webview",
    "<DOMAIN OF THE SAMPLE PAGE ABOVE>",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
  ],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {},
  "minimum_chrome_version": "28"
}
```

The Chrome App has some simple `newwindow` handling in it as well.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var webview = document.querySelector('#app-webview');
  webview.src = '<URL TO SAMPLE PAGE ABOVE>';
  webview.addEventListener('newwindow', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.open(e.targetUrl);
  });
};
```

Any suggestions on how to get downloads working (hopefully without requiring significant changes to the Ajax app)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File downloads from the webview guest are gated by a `permissionrequest` event per download attempt. The default response is to deny download permission.

*Note: The download permissionrequest will not land until Chrome 30 now, and it appears that documentation has not yet been made available. It is generally a stable API though, and it is unlikely to change between now and then.*

In order to override this behavior, you need to handle the event and explicitly allow the download to happen. As an example:

```
var webview = document.querySelector('#app-webview');
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
  if (e.permission === 'download') {
    e.request.allow();
  }
});
```

The event includes additional information (such as the download URL in `e.url`) in case you want to further filter your grants.

Be aware that this will only permit the download to happen using the regular Chrome file download experience, which isn't necessarily what you'll want from within a packaged app. Your options are limited until the `chrome.downloads` API is made available to apps.

One possibility is to deny the download request, grab the URL from the event, and manually manage the download process with XHR, the fileSystem API, and whatever UX you want to build.

Comment: According to https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/20803004/, this API was just made stable and will be available in Chrome 30.

Comment: Yeah I discovered today that it didn't make it into 29 yet, but it is being targeted for a merge.

Comment: Thanks very much @chomp. One slight fix for your example - you need to use `e.request.allow()` instead of `e.allow()`.

Comment: Update: This will not be making it into Chrome 29 after all.