# Chrome Packaged App written with DART : how to enable Webview tag to download files

Tags: google-chrome, webview, dart, google-chrome-app

I have this Chrome Packaged App written in DART, and I want to allow  tag to show the PDF comes as an attachment (Content-disposition:attachment; ) with HTTP response from an external link.Similar to the issue described here : [Chrome packaged application - downloading file from Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871097/chrome-packaged-application-downloading-file-from-webview) , but my app is in DART so there are some limitations. I am getting Permission error : ": The permission request for "download" has been denied." , I see a lot of examples on how to enable this from JS, but is there a way to do it with the Chrome API on DART ? or is there any other workaround to just display the PDF ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try dart-js-interop

```dart
var webview = document.querySelector('#app-webview');
webview.on['permissionrequest'].listen((e) {
  var evt = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e);
  if (evt['permission'] == 'download') {
    evt['request'].callMethod('allow', []);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this allows the download to work, but it places the file in the default downloads folder of the Chrome. How can the downloaded PDF file shown in the webview ? A bit like this : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/undisposition?hl=en

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue  but if you can shoe how to do it in JS I can probably tranlsze it to dart.